# passing $_GET string with alpha-nummeric value to SQL query in Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to pass an alpha-numerical value, that I fetch from an $_GET variable to an SQL-query. When I use a numerical value everything works fine, but I need to use strings that mix numerical and characters like e.g. '126A02249003192'.
I always get an error message and I tried to use the value blank, to typecast it with ::text or with to_char(), but nothing works.
Here the code I use:

```
$parameters='id_cadast = '.$_GET['id_cadast'].'::text';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE " . pg_escape_string($parameters);
```

Comment: and the error message would be ???

Comment: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "A02249003192" LINE 1: ...entroid FROM pcn_kerngebiete WHERE id_cadast = 126A022490031... ^ in

Comment: It is absolutly terrible  unsafe code. Please, read some doc about sql injection!

Answer (score 0):

You should escape only value and you should quote text value:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id_cadast = '" . pg_escape_string($_GET['id_cadast']) . "'";
```

Comment: In this case it works. The construct from above has the advantage, that I can define different parameters and other variables that are passed to the query string. And in this particular case I don't get it to work, which seems to be a problem with the right quotation.

Comment: `id_cadast` is probably text field. So query should looks `WHERE id_cadast = '126A02249003192'`. And implementation question: `"WHERE id_cadast = '" . $variable . "'"`

Comment: That is correct! My only problem is that I don't get it to work with the $parameters='...';  construct. With integer values it works like $parameters='gid='.$_GET['gid'].'; But not with text fields, which has to be in singles quotes.